# Instantiation exception while invoking setter at runtime using reflection

Tags: java

I have this model class that has a large number of strings. I want to sanitize each of the strings before I send them to the JSP. Here's my code:

```
public static void sanitize(Object obj) {
    for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            String name = Character.toUpperCase(field.getName().charAt(0)) + field.getName().substring(1);
            Method getter;
            Method setter;
            try {
                getter = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("get" + name);
                setter = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set" + name, field.getType());
                setter.invoke(obj.getClass().newInstance(),
                        sanitizeString(getter.invoke(obj.getClass().newInstance())));
                log.info("Done");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("{}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:** The setter invocation line is throwing an Instantiation exception. Now, I understand that the runtime object class may not have a no-args constructor.

Is there any way to avoid this? Will constructing a no-args constructor help at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you constructing a new instance and then calling the setter on that? Shouldn't you be calling the setter on the original object?

Comment: My bad. I just solved it. This is what you mean, right? setter.invoke(obj,sanitizeString(getter.invoke(obj)));

Comment: @kenster Add you comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setter.invoke(obj.getClass().newInstance(),
       sanitizeString(getter.invoke(obj.getClass().newInstance())));
```

You're creating new instances of the object's class and calling the getter and setter on those. Your intent is almost certainly to call the getter and setter on the original object. For that, you should pass the original object to `invoke()`:

```
setter.invoke(obj, sanitizeString(getter.invoke(obj)));
```